# Number of pages with structured data

Tags: google-search-console, structured-data

I'm using Webmaster Tools to track (beside other things) structured data, part of website is WordPress based, and part of it is custom developed website.

Until one month ago, Google reported that I have only few pages with structured data. After that, it started to report that I have about 200 pages with structured data (I don't know if WordPress was updated at that time).

After that, number of pages with structured data started to decrease, and now there is about 120 pages with it.

Can you help me and tell me why do I have decreased number of pages with structured data, and is good or bad?

Answer (score 1):

I joined the structured data party about 6 months ago (a little late to it I know), but I have noticed that there have been ups and downs in all the sites it is now in. As you can see from the graph below, randomly it decide there was no structured data before rebounding.

[image: structured data in webmaster tools]

I think it is important to remember that even Google has said structured data is going to evolve and hinted at it being a bit here and there. I don't have a reference link, but it is on Webmaster Tools somewhere.